# Out of memory exceptions Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a Tomcat 7 with a few applications installed, for now it's usual to upload new versions of the applications pretty fast: so I pack the war and undeploy the existing one and deploy the new war or redeploy an existing application, The problem comes few weeks later when I see that the memory is almost full in order to prevent some unexpected outofmemory exceptions that makes our customers without service

Do I have to restart time to time Tomcat? ¿Is that normal?
Is there a **pragmatic** solution for zero Tomcat restarts?

Please only expert answers

UPDATE: This library can really help to avoid permgem issues and classloader leaks:
https://github.com/mjiderhamn/classloader-leak-prevention, But remember that it's your responsability to not having leaks, there's no silver bullet. Visual VM can really help detecting classloader leaks.

Comment: I strongly suspect one/more application running on your Tomcat have coding issues which might be introducing memory leaks.

Comment: Hot deploy in java can be tricky, doing it wrong or with very subtle problems in your code can lead to all sorts of issues.  It can, however be done.  I assume you've read the tomcat docs on hot deploying?  If so, your best bet is to do it a few times on a test server and then examine the heap (I assume it's heap memory that's leaking?) to try to figure out what's going on

Comment: @Nambary some pragmatic solution to discover **that** application having coding issues that create memory leaks?

Comment: Google has tons of info on solving memory leaks, but just a warning: there is no simple solution.

Comment: @Taylor Well I think some Einstein solution is needed: 'simple as possible no simpler'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pragmatic solution for zero Tomcat restarts is coding applications that does not leak memory. It's that easy - Tomcat it not likely to leak that memory on it's own ;)
In other words: As long as your application is leaking memory restarting is unavoidable. You can tune memory settings, but you're just postponing the inevitable. 
Tomcat7 can detect some memory leaks (and even remedy some simple ones) - this feature is exposed through the Tomcat Manager if you install that. It does not, however, help you point our where the leak is.

Speaking from recent experience I had an app that did not seem to leak during normal operation, but had a PermGen leak - this means I do not really see the leak until I try to do what you're doing - hot deploy. I could only do a few deploys before filling the PermGen as Tomcat was unable to unload the old instance of the classes...
There may be better explanations of PermGen leak on the web, but a quick google gave me this: http://cdivilly.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/permgen-memory-leak/

If, however, your application crashes after running for some time it is likely that is has a proper memory leak. You can tune heap sizes and garbage collection settings in an attempt to remedy/work around this, but it may very well be that the only real fix is to track down the leak, fix the code and build a version that does not leak. 
...but unless you can ensure every release will be leak-free you need a strategy for restarting your service. If you don't do it during release, look into doing it off peak hours. 
If you have a cluster you can look into setting up Tomcat with memcached for session replication so as to not disrupt users when restarting a node in the cluster. You can also look into setting up monit, god, runit, upstart, systemd etc. for automatic restart of failed services...

Comment: Great answer, but just a comment: You can do your best to produce code that doesn't leak, but you have no control about thrid party libraries, for example I discovered some leaks from XMLBeans and JasperReports: Many users have complained about those leaks  but at this time remain unsolved

Comment: @NestorHernandezLoli Good point :) ...you could argue that those libraries are your responsibility as part of your application (maybe find older, non-leaking version?), though I know how these tings typically go. Anyway it's important to point out that there is no magical workaround for a memory leak :)

Comment: Mostly of those leaks that Tomcat complains are related to ThreadLocals not getting cleared, Jesus!, We are 2014, and they haven't realized that one must clear the fkn ThreadLocals. Just to mention that I don't think that these libraries are bad, but it's just a dumb thing that one shouldn't expect from skilled engineers

Comment: @NestorHernandezLoli I very much agree - the time 'saved' while coding on your product rather than learning how to do things right is very quickly spent debugging. In cases like these you end up making everyone else spend their time debugging too! ...but then again everyone makes mistakes :)

Answer (score 0):

You need add the VM arguments in the eclipse with minimum and maximum length. In eclipse goto window--> preferences-->click on Java-->click on installed JREs. then double click on jre record add the vm arguments as -Xms768m -Xmx1024m.